# Requiring password when restoring from sleep or screensaver

Tags: mac, security, screensaver

How do you require a password to be entered when restoring from sleep or screen saver?

Comment: Suggestion: specify "when waking from sleep or screensaver" (or something to that effect) in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an option in the Security preferences:

[image: Security prefs]

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Apple icon at the top left of the screen on the menu bar.
2. Click "System Preferences...".
3. Click to Open "Security".

Check "Require password to wake this computer from sleep or screen saver"

Comment: Is there a reason you answered your own question? Is it because you figured it out already?

Comment: I figured it out after I asked but didn't refresh the answers before I answered it.  Thanks.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with answering your own question. Of course, it'd be best to hit refresh first.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences -> Security -> Check "Require password to take this computer from sleep or screen saver"

Answer (score 0):

User Preferences->Security->General tab.  Contains check boxes for "Require password to wake this computer from sleep or screen saver" and "Disable automatic login."